# simplejson.dumps not accepting string format

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

simplejson.dumps works like this:

```
package_specs=
{"Starter":{"QUOTA":1000,"BANDWIDTH":10000,"EMAILS":1000,"ADDONS":0,"PARKED":0,"SUBS":1000,"DBS":1000},
"Test":{"QUOTA":555,"BANDWIDTH":6666,"EMAILS":444,"ADDONS":33,"PARKED":22,"SUBS":77,"DBS":888},
"Default":{"QUOTA":1000,"BANDWIDTH":10000,"EMAILS":10,"ADDONS":0,"PARKED":0,"SUBS":0,"DBS":5}}
```

But not with `package_specs` as a string returned from a program, which generates the package specs, which would be something like this:

```
package_specs=
'{"Starter":{"QUOTA":1000,"BANDWIDTH":10000,"EMAILS":1000,"ADDONS":0,"PARKED":0,"SUBS":1000,"DBS":1000},
"Test":{"QUOTA":555,"BANDWIDTH":6666,"EMAILS":444,"ADDONS":33,"PARKED":22,"SUBS":77,"DBS":888},
"Default":{"QUOTA":1000,"BANDWIDTH":10000,"EMAILS":10,"ADDONS":0,"PARKED":0,"SUBS":0,"DBS":5}}'
```

The result on the page is:

```
Default
0 {
1 "
2 Q
3 U
4 O
5 T
6 A
7 "
8 :
9 1
10 0
11 0
12 0
13 ,
14 "
15 B
16 A
17 N
18 D
19 W
20 I
21 D
22 T
23 H
etc.
```

And in my render function, to pass the json dumps to a `mako` template, I have:

```
package_specs=simplejson.dumps(package_specs,sort_keys=True),
```

How can I get package_specs in the format needed for json?

I tried a dict but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

the first example is a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) the second is a `string representation of JSON`

to convert json to string you use `json.dumps`

```
json.dumps({"foo": "bar"})
```

to convert string to json you use `json.loads`

```
json.loads('{"foo": "bar"}')
```